# XCode Throwing Errors @implementation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, implementation

I'm trying to learn some of the basics of developing OS X apps with XCode and Objective-C, but I am already running into problems.

I have a project I made from a while back which worked very well for me, however, when I try to replicate the results I had last time, I run into numerous errors.

I have two files, a .c and a .h named "AppDelegate"

in AppDelegate.h:

```
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
    #import <WebKit/WebView.h>

    @interface AppDelegate : NSObject {
        IBOutlet WebView *gameFrame;
    }

    @end
```

then, in AppDelegate.c:

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

    @implementation AppDelegate
    -(void)awakeFromNib
    {

    }
    @end
```

In IB, there is an NSObject named 'AppDelegate' and its class is 'AppDelegate'.

However, when I try to run this, I get **11734** errors...

When I click on the error icon at the bottom of the XCode window, it lists a bunch of code that seems to be involving NSStrings, but I cant make any sense of it...

Also, within my code, the

```
    @end
```

line in both the .c and the .h are highlighted with an error saying:

```
'Expected identifier or '(' before '@' token.'
```

I don't understand what XCode is tripping up on when it tries to compile, I don't see any logical place for a '(' to go and I don't think I left anything unidentified.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because that isn't valid C code.

You named your module file `AppDelegate.c`, which indicates that it contains source code written in (more or less) pure C. But it does not: You wrote a class interface and implementation in Objective-C, which is a superset of C (all C is valid Objective-C, but not all Objective-C is valid C—in particular, classes aren't).

For this, you must name the module file `AppDelegate.m` (or anything else, as long as it ends with `.m`; naming it after the class is a convention worth following). The `.m` suffix indicates a module (usually containing a class implementation) written in Objective-C.

So, just rename your module file from `AppDelegate.c` to `AppDelegate.m`. Make sure you do this in Xcode, not the Finder: If you do it in the Finder, Xcode will only care that there is no longer a file named AppDelegate.c; it won't notice the rename.

For your convenience in creating future classes, Xcode provides a template in the “New File” panel for creating subclasses of certain Cocoa classes; your AppDelegate should be a subclass of NSObject, and templates are also provided for NSView, NSDocument, UIView, UIViewController, and a few others. The files created by the template will already have the correct extensions.

Comment: Wow, awesome. Not only did you tell me how to solve my problem, you told me what was going wrong, how to prevent it in the future, and gave some great advice. Thanks a ton man!